# How to create a linked server to connect to an analysis service on azure

Tags: sql-server, linked-server, azure-analysis-services

I have a SQL Server.  I would like to create a linked server connecting to an Azure Analysis Services that is hosted on Azure. I followed the instructions and discussions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/276132/creating-linked-server-to-connect-to-azure-analysi.html. Instead, I kept on getting the following error message when trying to connect. Cannot find any helpful info on the Error 7373. If anyone has solved similar issues, please help. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 0):

***To Connect as a linked server from SQL Server***

By designating MSOLAP as the data source provider, SQL Server will establish a Linked server connection to an Azure Analysis Services resource. To create connection, Install the most recent version of the [MSOLAP client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/client-libraries?view=azure-analysis-services-current&preserve-view=true)  (provider) before setting a linked server connection.

Then go to Object Explorer >> under your server go to Server Objects >> Providers >> Right click on, MSOLAP >> Properties >> uncheck the `Allow Inprocess` >> Click on OK.

[image]

In Azure Analysis Service create a new model.

[image]

open Object Explorer, expand Server Objects, right-click Linked Servers, and then click New Linked Server.

```
Provider =  Microsoft OLE DB Provider  for  Analysis  Services  14.0
Product  Name = MSOLAP
Datasource =  Analysis services Server name
Provider  string =  Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=<server name>;Initial Catalog=<model name created in above step>
```

[image]

**Linked server created successfully**

[image]

Comment: Thank you PratikLad. What did you put for the Provider? Just MSOLAP? Thanks

Comment: for provider I put `Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 14.0` and for Product Name I gave `MSOLAP`

Comment: I meant the fourth line in the second image. The content of the line is hidden. Thanks.

Comment: the provider string you can get it from portal directly from connection strings.